# Spring + AS400: stored procedures parameter type error

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

I'm having a problem calling an AS400 stored procedure from Spring. In the logs it seems that can't make the call because of the parameters, saying: "CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call SEXCA01(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [HY105]; error code [-99999]; Parameter type not valid.;"

The call in Java is made by the following code

```
public SEXCA01(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    super(jdbcTemplate, "SEXCA01");
    configure();
}

private void configure() {
    this.declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PIDI, Types.CHAR));
    this.declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTS, Types.CHAR));
    this.declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTC, Types.CHAR));
    this.declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PSQLCOD, Types.INTEGER));
    this.declareParameter(new SqlInOutParameter(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PRET, Types.CHAR));
    this.declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("resultset", rwMapFindAllConsejeros));
}
```

The following would be the calling method to this class:

```
    public List<Consejero> getAll() throws ConsejoException {
        List<Consejero> listaConsejeros = new ArrayList<Consejero>();
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        IProcedureBase procedure = new SEXCA01(jdbcTemplate);
        try {
            resultMap = procedure.executeStoredProcedure(processParametersGetAll("ES"));
            if(!(resultMap.get(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTS).toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                logger.error((String) resultMap.get(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTS));
                throw new ConsejeroDaoException(resultMap.get(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTS).toString());
            }
            listaConsejeros = (ArrayList<Consejero>)resultMap.get("resultSet");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new ConsejeroDaoException(e.getMessage());
        }   
        return listaConsejeros;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> processParametersGetAll(String language) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PIDI, language);
        params.put(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTS, "");
        params.put(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PERRTXTC, "");
        params.put(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PSQLCOD, 0);       
        params.put(BaseDao.PARAMETER_PRET, "");
        return params;
    }
```

And in the AS400 procedure, params are declared like this:

```
 D Entry           PR                  EXTPGM('SEXCA01')
 D                                2                     
 D                               60                     
 D                               78                     
 D                                5i 0                  
 D                                1                     
  *                                                     
 D Entry           PI                                   
 D  pidi                          2                     
 D  perrtxts                     60                     
 D  perrtxtc                     78                     
 D  psqlcod                       5i 0                  
 D  pret                          1
```

Finally, to compile the stored procedure, I used this SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXPOBJEX/SEXCA01 
   (IN PIDI CHAR(2),              
   OUT PERRTXTS CHAR(60),         
   OUT PERRTXTC CHAR(78),         
   OUT PSQLCOD CHAR(1),           
   OUT PRET CHAR(1))              
   DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1          
   LANGUAGE RPGLE                 
   READS SQL DATA                 
   EXTERNAL NAME EXPOBJEX/SEXCA01 
   PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
```

Anybody can help me with this little issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the procedure has 1 input and 4 output parameters.  I'm guessing that the definition needs to match.

Comment: Also, it looks like the 4th parameter is defined as CHAR(1) in the create procedure, but should really be int.